# How do you get comments from a GTLYouTubeActivity?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

Easy question, but the answer eludes me in the docs.

I have a GTLYouTubeActivityListResponse from a GTLQueryYouTube queryForActivitiesListWithPart:

the NSArray of GTLYouTubeActivity-s are all exactly what I want, but tip toeing through the structures, I'm not seeing any NSString* "comment" "text" etc.

So.. simple question, once I have a GTLYouTubeActivity, how can I get the comment string associated with that?

Thanks in advance.